# How was the final episode of Do No Harm intended?

Tags: ending, do-no-harm

Was the final episode of Do No Harm written with the knowledge that it would be the final episode of the series, or with the intention that it was the final episode of the season?

If you have seen the final episode you will most likely understand what I am getting at:

> In the final scenes, you learn that Jason is the alter and that Dr. Carmello intends to suppress the part of Ian's brain that contains Jason. You also notice a surgical scar in the area that is being operated on.

This leads me to believe that the writers did not intend this to be the end of the series.

I feel that it would be way too much of a rip-off ending, and they would probably not have done this.

Comment: i don't know why they canceled i was starting to enjoy it

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you think *Do No Harm's* ending is not what it intended to be. I haven't watched the show, but I think the reason might be the conflict between NBC and the show's owners.

> On November 12, 2012, NBC reduced its episode order for the series
>   from 13 to 12 episodes, due to scheduling conflicts.
>
> On February 8, 2013, it was announced that NBC had canceled the series after airing two episodes, due to low ratings. On April 26,
>   2013, NBC announced that the remaining episodes would be burned off,
>   beginning June 29, 2013.- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_No_Harm_%28TV_series%29)

Comment: What I am wondering is if the writers knew the 12th episode would be the end of the series when they wrote it?

Comment: Using the info you found,  can we assume either that the 12 episodes were written/filmed to completion before the series cancel order was given, or that the episodes were not all written/filmed to completion before the series cancel order was given, allowing the writers to tailor the remaining episodes accordingly?

Comment: @user27008 there is no other clear detail given, so we can only speculated further.

Answer (score -4):

all episodes of Do No Harm were completed before the pilot aired in january 2013.  i think it was written surely to have a season 2.

Comment: Is this meant to be a comment on another answer?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Whilst your opinions are very welcome, this doesn't actually _answer_ the question. It would be better left as a comment under the first post. For more information on how the site works, take the Tour under the Help menu.